# Keras LSTM layer output and the output of a numpy LSTM implementation are similar but not same with the same weights and Input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I modeled a two layered LSTM Keras model then I compared the output of the first LSTM layer with my simple python implementation of the LSTM layer by feeding in the same weights and Inputs. The results for the first sequence of a batch are similar but not same and from the second sequence the results deviates too far.
Below is my keras model:
For comparison of the Keras model I first created an intermediate layer where the intermediate layer outputs the result of the first layer with `print(intermediate_output[0,0])`for the first sequence and `print(intermediate_output[0][1])` for the second sequence of the same batch then `print(intermediate_output[0][127])` for the last sequence.

```
inputs = Input(shape=(128,9))
f1=LSTM((n_hidden),return_sequences=True,name='lstm1')(inputs)
f2=LSTM((n_hidden), return_sequences=False,name='lstm2')(f1)
 fc=Dense(6,activation='softmax',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(lambda_loss_amount),name='fc')(f2)
    model2 = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=fc)

layer_name = 'lstm1'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model2.input,
                                 outputs=model2.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(X_single_sequence[0,:,:])
print(intermediate_output[0,0]) # takes input[0][9]
print(intermediate_output[0][1]) # takes input[1][9] and hidden layer output of intermediate_output[0,0]
print(intermediate_output[0][127])
```

Re-Implemented first layer of the same model:
I defined `LSTMlayer` function where it does the same computation....after that `weightLSTM` loads the saved weights and `x_t` the same input sequence and later on `h_t` contains outputs for the next sequence. `intermediate_out` is a function corresponding to that of LSTM layer.

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return(1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-x)))
def LSTMlayer(warr,uarr, barr,x_t,h_tm1,c_tm1):
    '''
    c_tm1 = np.array([0,0]).reshape(1,2)
    h_tm1 = np.array([0,0]).reshape(1,2)
    x_t   = np.array([1]).reshape(1,1)

    warr.shape = (nfeature,hunits*4)
    uarr.shape = (hunits,hunits*4)
    barr.shape = (hunits*4,)
    '''

    s_t = (x_t.dot(warr) + h_tm1.dot(uarr) + barr)
    hunit = uarr.shape[0]
    i  = sigmoid(s_t[:,:hunit])
    f  = sigmoid(s_t[:,1*hunit:2*hunit])
    _c = np.tanh(s_t[:,2*hunit:3*hunit])
    o  = sigmoid(s_t[:,3*hunit:])
    c_t = i*_c + f*c_tm1
    h_t = o*np.tanh(c_t)

    return(h_t,c_t)

weightLSTM = model2.layers[1].get_weights()
warr,uarr, barr = weightLSTM
warr.shape,uarr.shape,barr.shape

def intermediate_out(n,warr,uarr,barr,X_test):
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        if i==0:
            c_tm1 = np.array([0]*hunits, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1,32)
            h_tm1 = np.array([0]*hunits, dtype=np.float32).reshape(1,32)
            h_t,ct = LSTMlayer(warr,uarr, barr,X_test[0][0:1][0:9],h_tm1,c_tm1)
        else:
            h_t,ct = LSTMlayer(warr,uarr, barr,X_test[0][i:i+1][0:9],h_t,ct)
    return h_t

# 1st sequence

ht0 = intermediate_out(0,warr,uarr,barr,X_test)

# 2nd sequence

ht1 = intermediate_out(1,warr,uarr,barr,X_test)
# 128th sequence 

ht127 = intermediate_out(127,warr,uarr,barr,X_test)
```

The outputs of the keras LSTM layer from `print(intermediate_output[0,0])` are as follows:

```
array([-0.05616369, -0.02299516, -0.00801201,  0.03872827,  0.07286803,
   -0.0081161 ,  0.05235862, -0.02240333,  0.0533984 , -0.08501752,
   -0.04866522,  0.00254417, -0.05269946,  0.05809477, -0.08961852,
    0.03975506,  0.00334282, -0.02813114,  0.01677909, -0.04411673,
   -0.06751891, -0.02771493, -0.03293832,  0.04311397, -0.09430656,
   -0.00269871, -0.07775293, -0.11201388, -0.08271968, -0.07464679,
   -0.03533605, -0.0112953 ], dtype=float32)
```

and the outputs of my implementation from `print(ht0)` are:

```
array([[-0.05591469, -0.02280132, -0.00797964,  0.03681555,  0.06771626,
    -0.00855897,  0.05160453, -0.02309707,  0.05746563, -0.08988875,
    -0.05093143,  0.00264367, -0.05087904,  0.06033305, -0.0944235 ,
     0.04066657,  0.00344291, -0.02881387,  0.01696692, -0.04101779,
    -0.06718517, -0.02798996, -0.0346873 ,  0.04402719, -0.10021093,
    -0.00276826, -0.08390114, -0.1111543 , -0.08879325, -0.07953986,
    -0.03261982, -0.01175724]], dtype=float32)
```

The outputs from `print(intermediate_output[0][1])`:

```
array([-0.13193817, -0.03231169, -0.02096735,  0.07571879,  0.12657365,
    0.00067896,  0.09008797, -0.05597101,  0.09581321, -0.1696091 ,
   -0.08893952, -0.0352162 , -0.07936387,  0.11100324, -0.19354928,
    0.09691346, -0.0057206 , -0.03619875,  0.05680932, -0.08598096,
   -0.13047703, -0.06360915, -0.05707538,  0.09686109, -0.18573627,
    0.00711019, -0.1934243 , -0.21811798, -0.15629804, -0.17204499,
   -0.07108577,  0.01727455], dtype=float32)
```

`print(ht1)`:

```
 array([[-1.34333193e-01, -3.36792655e-02, -2.06091907e-02,
     7.15097040e-02,  1.18231244e-01,  7.98894180e-05,
     9.03479978e-02, -5.85013032e-02,  1.06357656e-01,
    -1.82848617e-01, -9.50253978e-02, -3.67032290e-02,
    -7.70251378e-02,  1.16113290e-01, -2.08772928e-01,
     9.89214852e-02, -5.82863577e-03, -3.79538871e-02,
     6.01535551e-02, -7.99121782e-02, -1.31876275e-01,
    -6.66067824e-02, -6.15542643e-02,  9.91254672e-02,
    -2.00229391e-01,  7.51443207e-03, -2.13641390e-01,
    -2.18286291e-01, -1.70858681e-01, -1.88928470e-01,
    -6.49823472e-02,  1.72227081e-02]], dtype=float32)
```

`print(intermediate_output[0][127])`:

```
array([-0.46212202,  0.280646  ,  0.514289  , -0.21109435,  0.53513926,
        0.20116206,  0.24579187,  0.10773794, -0.6350403 , -0.0052841 ,
       -0.15971565,  0.00309152,  0.04909453,  0.29789132,  0.24909772,
        0.12323025,  0.15282209,  0.34281147, -0.2948742 ,  0.03674917,
       -0.22213924,  0.17646286, -0.12948939,  0.06568322,  0.04172657,
       -0.28638166, -0.29086435, -0.6872528 , -0.12620741,  0.63395363,
       -0.37212485, -0.6649531 ], dtype=float32)
```

`print(ht127)`:

```
array([[-0.47431907,  0.29702517,  0.5428258 , -0.21381126,  0.6053808 ,
         0.22849198,  0.25656056,  0.10378123, -0.6960949 , -0.09966939,
        -0.20533416, -0.01677105,  0.02512029,  0.37508538,  0.35703233,
         0.14703275,  0.24901289,  0.35873395, -0.32249793,  0.04093777,
        -0.20691746,  0.20096642, -0.11741923,  0.06169611,  0.01019177,
        -0.33316574, -0.08499744, -0.6748463 , -0.06659956,  0.71961826,
        -0.4071832 , -0.6804066 ]], dtype=float32)
```

The outputs from (`print(intermediate_output[0,0])`, `print(h_t[0])`) and (`print(intermediate_output[0][1])`, `print(h_t1)`) are similar...but the output from `print(intermediate_output[0][127])` and `print(h_t127)` not same and both the algorithms are implemented on the same gpu...

I saw the keras documentation and to me it seems that I am not doing anything wrong....Please comment on this and let me know that what else am I missing here ??

Comment: is the initialization of the weights the same?

Comment: Weights are already trained and just loaded in both the keras and my python implementation

Comment: Could there be a bug in your numpy implementation of LSTM? Have you tried calling the keras LSTM in tf eager instead of using numpy, to guarantee you're using the same code?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos I called Keras LSTM in tf eager but how can I access the values after computations like input gate, forget gate, new candidate cell,output gate....out of Keras LSTM to debug my code and see the fault with my implementation ?

Comment: I found the solution....I am using sigmoid and keras is using hard_sigmoid...